# Cannot get custom post type thumbnail/featured image to show in WordPress admin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, thumbnails, wordpress-featured-image

I have created three custom post types with support for thumbnails and I am trying to create a column in the admin/edit screen for the featured image/thumbnail, but I'm having no success.

The custom post types are 'publicPages', 'patreonPages', and 'exclusivePages'

This is the code I've seen people say works that I have modified for my post types:

```
function add_featured_image_column($defaults) {
    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Featured Image';
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('manage_publicPages_posts_columns', 'add_featured_image_column');
add_filter('manage_patreonPages_posts_columns', 'add_featured_image_column');
add_filter('manage_exclusivePages_posts_columns', 'add_featured_image_column');
 
function show_featured_image_column($column_name, $id) {
    if ($column_name == 'featured_image') {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'thumbnail'); 
    }
}
add_action('manage_publicPages_posts_custom_column', 'show_featured_image_column', 10, 2);
add_action('manage_patreonPages_posts_custom_column', 'show_featured_image_column', 10, 2);
add_action('manage_exclusivePages_posts_custom_column', 'show_featured_image_column', 10, 2);
```

but it hasn't worked. The rest of my CPT/child theme is working just fine - it's just this bit that I keep running into trouble with.

Happy to provide additional info as needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the slug of your custom post types? Maybe you can provide the code, where you defined the custom post types.

Comment: @rank - the code for the CPTs is here: https://github.com/moon-ent/jakeshandy/blob/main/CPTs

Comment: When you register your post type, you are not allowed to use camel case name. This could cause the problem when using 'manage_POSTTYPE_posts_...' hooks.
Please have a look: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/
"Post type key. Must not exceed 20 characters and may only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes, and underscores"

Comment: I figured it out with some help from a guy I work with. Thanks though!